# How to get JSON parameter through XHR

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to retreive the "test" parameter in the MVC View using XHR?

```
 return Json(new
        {
            sEcho = param.sEcho,
            iTotalRecords = totalRows,
            iTotalDisplayRecords = totalRows,
            aaData = jsonArray,
            test = "testing..."
        },
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

My View

```
 var oTable = $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
            "sAjaxSource": "Directory/TableAjaxHandler",
            "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
                $('#panelBody').scrollTop(50);
            },
            "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, json) {
              alert("test");
            }
        });
```

How do I get the test parameter in the razor (MVC3) View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning a `Json` ActionResult has no view because the output of the Controller is the `Json`

Using the latest AJAX methods in jQuery (1.8+) you'd do this to access the json object:

```
request = $.ajax({
    url: "/Controller/Action",
    type: "POST",
    data: serializedData
});

// callback handler that will be called on success
request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
    //add your code here...
});
```

Earlier versions of jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  url : "Controller/Action",
  type: "POST",
  data : formData,
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
  {
    //data - response from server
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
  {

  }
});
```

Comment: Yes the output is Json. However I need a way to get the value of test from XHR (XMLHttpRequest) inside my View ??

Comment: Show where you call the Controller in your javascript.

Comment: I have updated my code above: The datatable plugin is creating the request to my controller action. In the fnInitComplete is where I want to retreive the test object/string.

Comment: is it firing that event?  is the `json` argument populated?

Comment: Well "the json object request from the server - only present if client-side Ajax sourced data is used" so I guess its not populated. However, this does not hold true when using external language information since that is obtained using an async XHR call.

Comment: this is seems to be more about the `dataTable` than anything else, I've not ever used it.

Comment: just used your code above in another function return, it works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

call your JsonResult action like below

```
$.getJSON("url_of_action", function(data) {
 console.log(data);
 alert(data.test);
});
```